# How to dynamically choose an object type based on a JSON string value with Jackson library in Java?

Tags: java, json, oop, server, jackson

I am currently developping a whiteboard application for a student project. We have to write a whole protocol from scratch and I went for a text-based approach, for which I use JSON messages. The backend server, which replies to the client requests, is written in **Java**.

The way I handle incoming messages at the moment is done through a **WebSocket server**. The string that contains the JSON message is mapped to an object that I defined as *SuperMessage* through an **ObjectMapper** with the *mapper.readValue()* function. The **SuperMessage** class is defined as followed:

```
public class SuperMessage {

    private MessageType type;
    private JsonNode object;

    @JsonCreator
    public SuperMessage(@JsonProperty("type") MessageType type, @JsonProperty("object") JsonNode object) {
        this.type = type;
        this.object = object;
    }
    // Getters here
}
```

The *type* attribute is here to indicate what kind of message it is, and the *object* attribute contains the payload, which is a serialized object of the same type as the one indicated in the *type* attribute. Therefore, in my protocol, a JSON message has always the following structure:

```
{
    "type":"<message_type>",
    "object": {
        "attribute_1": "<value_1>",
        "attribute_2": "<value_2>",
        "sub_object": {
            "sub_attribute_1": "<sub_value_1>",
            "sub_attribute_2": "<sub_value_2>"
        }
    }
}
```

Once this message is created, I use a **switch** statement on the *type* field from the JSON message to know what to do with that specific message. I have the following bit of code in the definition of the *onMessage()* function:

```
@Override
public void onMessage(WebSocket conn, String message) {
    try {
        SuperMessage msg = mapper.readValue(message, SuperMessage.class);
        System.out.println("Message type is: " + msg.getType() + " and message payload is: " + msg.getObject());
        String messageString = msg.getObject().toString();
        // For each case of the switch, errors still need to be considered and handled through exceptions
        switch (msg.getType()) {
            case CREATE_MEETING:
                CreateMeeting createMeeting = mapper.readValue(messageString, CreateMeeting.class);
                // more code
                break;
                // other cases
       }
   }
}
```

I use the **switch cases** to know what kind of message I am dealing with, and then create the instance of the corresponding class. This is where I am stuck and I don't know how to proceed. Let's say I receive the following JSON message:

```
{
  "type": "CreateMeeting",
  "object": {
    "messageId": "123456",
    "pseudo": "bob123"
  }
}
```

Now, I would like to create an object of type **CreateMeeting**. However, I would like to do it in a generic manner, as I don't know in advance what kind of message I will be receiving, and I don't want to add new **switch cases** for each type of new message that I define. I know this is wrong code but that's what I would like to write:

```
@Override
public void onMessage(WebSocket conn, String message) {
    try {
        SuperMessage msg = mapper.readValue(message, SuperMessage.class);
        System.out.println("Message type is: " + msg.getType() + " and message payload is: " + msg.getObject());
        String messageString = msg.getObject().toString();
        String className = msg.getType().toString(); // Now, className = "CreateMessage";
        // Now messageObject's type would be CreateMessage
        Object messageObject = mapper.readValue(messageString, className.class); // This code is wrong
   }
}
```

**Is there a way to do that? To dynamically map a JSON message to an object type that is not known in advance?**

I am quite new to OOP, and I am sure that experienced programmers here would say this code is not clean at all. I am really looking for any kind of advice and/or methods to make this better and optimized.

Thanks in advance for any recommendations!

Comment: Jackson does all of this for you - search engine keywords : 'jackson polymorphism'. There are many styles and options to play with so the best advice is to dig into this long but thorough writeup https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-inheritance

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I did not know how to look for what I wanted to do, and the keywords you provided enabled me to find what I was looking for.